# How to create a dictionary with value list from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe, like so:

| Projects | Goals | Steps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project A | Goal 1 | NaN |
| Project A | NaN | Step 1 |
| Project A | NaN | Step 2 |
| Project A | Goal 2 | NaN |
| Project A | NaN | Step 3 |
| Project A | NaN | Step 4 |

It's not sorted by projects, I just wanted to make it easier to understand with one example.

I'm trying to create a dictionary out of it, in the following format:
dict = {Project A: {Goal 1 : [Step 1, Step 2], Goal 2 : [Step 3, Step 4]}, Project B...}

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your dictionary by grouping successively by 'Projects' and 'Goals' aggregating the steps with `list`:

```
df["Goals"] = df['Goals'].ffill()
df = df.dropna()

dict_out = {}

for proj, sub_df in df.groupby('Projects'):
    sub_df = sub_df.drop('Projects', axis=1).groupby(['Goals']).agg(list)
    dict_out.update({proj: sub_df.to_dict()['Steps']})

print(dict_out)
```

Output:

```
{'Project A': {'Goal 1': ['Step 1', 'Step 2'], 'Goal 2': ['Step 3', 'Step 4']}}
```

Edit: forgot ffill and dropna in my copy/paste

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! My output with your code is:
{'Project A': {'Goal 1': [nan], 'Goal 2': [nan]}}

I tried debugging your code and noted that it only goes through the for-loop once. Is that intended?

Also, what does groupby('Projects') do? Isn't the df already grouped by that?

Comment: Did you use ffill and dropna at the beginning (I had forgotten to copy these lines in my initial post)? It goes through the loop only once because your example has only one project

Comment: Now I did and now it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tranbi - Good Attempt +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: Dealing with nans
Step-2: Groupby project then groupby Goals and create dictionary

This could help you,

```
df['Goals'] = df['Goals'].fillna(method='ffill')
df = df.dropna()
{k: f.groupby('Goals', dropna=True)['Steps'].apply(list).to_dict()
     for k, f in df.groupby('Projects')}
```

Alternative Solution:

```
df.groupby(['Goals']).agg({'Steps': list, 'Projects': 'first'}).groupby(['Projects']).agg(dict).reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

O/P:

```
{'Project A': {'Goal 1': ['Step 1', 'Step 2'], 'Goal 2': ['Step 3', 'Step 4']}}
```